# AngularJS: String and variable in curly braces

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a variable `username` and a variable `userid`.
I want to display the name and the id in brackets it in an `input` like this:

```
Name (ID)
```

In angularjs I do `<input value="{{username}} ({{userid}})" />` which leads to an ugly `()` when `username` and `userid` are empty.

Is there an easier way than using `ng-if` to solve my problem.
Something like `{{ username + "(" + userid + ")"}}`?

Comment: What would you like to display if userid is null?

Comment: The value should be empty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This jsfiddle presents 4 options. choose whatever suits you better:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Su6udFHxIVEWmEpvulXZ?p=preview

1. Use only angular expression:

   `{{ name ? '(' + name + ')' : ''}}`

I wouldn't use this most of the time, it's just the most straight forward way to do it if you don't need anything reusable.

1. Create a filter to display the user id:

   `app.filter('userIdDisplay', function () {
     return function (input) {
       return input ? '(' + input + ')' : '';
     };
   });`

   `{{ name | userIdDisplay }}`

I'd use this if you have a very specific formatting that is more complicated than just the parenthesis

1. Create a generic filter to display a string if some variable has a truthy value:

   `app.filter('ifExists', function () {
     return function (input, variable) {
       return variable ? input : '';
     };
   });`

   `{{ '(' + name + ')' | ifExists:name }}`

I'd use this for a strings with a simple display, like only adding parenthesis.

1. Use ng-if or ng-show and wrap with a span:

   `<span ng-if="name">({{ name }})</span>`

This I'd use if it's not only string formatting, but you also want to display other directives or plain html tags conditionally.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to need either the ng-if or an ng-show. If you want to keep the element visible maybe you can try this:

```
{{ username && userId ? (username + "(" + userid + ")") : "" }}
```

Might need to be edited to handle empty spaces/zeros.